# Compute the sum of the square of integers

Tags: c

I'm kind of confused on a question my professor gave us as homework.The question ask to write a program that "computes the sum of the squares of the integers", and I'm a little confused as to what that means exactly. The question comes from C Primer Plus 6th Edition (questions 5 & 6, if anyone has the book).

I wrote the following, part of it came from a different question.

```
int main()
{

    int count;
    int sum;
    int howFar;

    count = 0;
    sum = 0;


    printf("Enter a number: ");

    scanf("%d", &howFar);

    while (count++ < howFar) {
        sum = sum + count;
        //is this what it means????
        sum = sum * sum;
    }

    printf("sum = %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "The sum of the squares of the integers". This means if we are given 1, 2,3, 4 we would do `1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 = 1 + 4 + 9 + 16 = 30`

Comment: It is the usual incomprehensible language describing mathematical simplicity:  Sum i * i

Comment: So, if the number the user entered was 20, you're saying it would square each number until the while loop ends?

Comment: find the square of count, and *then* add it to sum. Also, start from 1 and go up to and including howFar. Try putting a printf inside the loop to print out sum at each step to check that it is correct

Answer (score 0):

Sum of square of integers for 3 numbers means 1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3 = 14 
the code may help you

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int count,sum=0,temp;
    printf("Enter the total number you e=want to sum up");
    scanf("%d",&count);//variable to hold count of total number you want to sum up 
    while(count){
        count--; //decrement count by one
        printf("Enter number for square sum");
        scanf("%d",&temp);//variable to hold coming number for sum 
        sum = sum + (temp*temp); //square and sum
    }
    printf("sum = %d\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple formula for the sum of squares from `1` to a positive value `n` (i.e. `1 + 4 + 9 + .... + (n*n)`)  is `n*(n+1)*(2*n + 1)/6`.

Depending on value of `n`, you will need to check for overflow, since integral types in C have upper limits on the range of values they can represent.   This is equally true using a formula or a loop.